# find max and min in array in java

Tags: java, arrays, function, element

I have wordpad file. And i read its elements and write into array. Then I must find its max and min then I find all first column's elements average. Then I take first column elements and write this formula  `x1=(x1-average)/s // max-min=S` and I must write it in method ( function ). How can I do it ? where do I write this method? This is my program code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    double teta0= 0;
    double teta1= 0;
    double teta2= 0;
    double alpha = 0.1;
    double temp0;
    double temp1;
    double temp2;
    double J;
    double h;
    double sumJ;
    double sumTemp0=0;
    double sumTemp1=0;
    double sumtemp2=0;
    double x1 ;

    double array [][] = new double [47][3];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Grundig\\Downloads\\ex1data2.txt"));

    int k=0;  
    while ( sc.hasNextLine()){
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        array[k][0]=Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[0]);
        array[k][1]=Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]);
        array[k][2]=Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[2]);
        k++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        sumJ = 0;
        sumTemp0 = 0;
        sumTemp1 = 0;
        double sumTemp2 = 0;

        for (int j=0;j<47;j++){    
            h = teta0 + teta1*array[j][0]+teta2*array[j][1];

            sumJ= sumJ + Math.pow((h-array[j][2]),2);            
            sumTemp0= sumTemp0 + (h-array[j][2]); 
            sumTemp1= sumTemp1 + (h-array[j][2])*array[j][0];  
            sumTemp2= sumTemp2 + (h-array[j][2])*array[j][1];
        }

        J = sumJ/(2*47); 

        System.out.println((i+1)+".J=" +J);

        temp0 = teta0 - alpha*sumTemp0/47;
        temp1 = teta1 - alpha*sumTemp1/47;
        temp2 = teta2 - alpha*sumTemp2/47;
        teta0 = temp0;
        teta1 = temp1;
        teta2 = temp2;

     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lena.IT, welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is full with nice people willing to help you, but there are some basic rules. We expect you to give straight questions, and show your efforts on solving the problem. Unfortunately this is not a site where you will get learn basic programming. Can you phrase your question please? :) How to find the min or max of an array? Or how to write a method?

Comment: I'd suggest https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html see "defining methods". It is also a nice idea to give a simple working example focusing on the problem you have. For example, once file reading works, you may leave that code out (and no one will ask for the missing input file either).